# Nested Array Tree Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am comparing 2 arrays with the ID's and adding nested children objects to generate the tree.

if you look in the code comparing `issue_id` with `descendents_parent_issue_id`

I am able to generate the tree but a children is adding only 1 object. Expecting tree level nested objects.

`Following Code Output`

```
[{
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "children": [{
        "issue_id": 7,
        "parent_issue_id": 2,
        "issue": "Breakdown",
        "issue_code": "bd7catA",
        "entity_id": null,
        "hierarchy_level": 2,
        "children": [{
            "issue_id": 881,
            "parent_issue_id": 7,
            "issue": "Hydraulic arm failure",
            "issue_code": null,
            "entity_id": 52,
            "hierarchy_level": 3
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "issue_id": 1,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Loading",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
}, {
    "issue_id": 3,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Performance",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
}, {
    "issue_id": 4,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Quality",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
}]
```

`My Code`

```js
const issuesList = [
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 1,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Loading",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 3,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Performance",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 4,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Quality",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  }
];

const issues = [{
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
    "descendents_issue": "Breakdown",
    "descendents_issue_code": "bd7catA",
    "descendents_entity_id": null,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 2,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 881,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_issue": "Hydraulic arm failure",
    "descendents_issue_code": null,
    "descendents_entity_id": 52,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 3,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 881,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 8,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
    "descendents_issue": "Setup/ Changeover",
    "descendents_issue_code": "st8catA",
    "descendents_entity_id": null,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 2,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 8,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 942,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_issue": "Pump Overload",
    "descendents_issue_code": null,
    "descendents_entity_id": 52,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 3,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 942,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  }
  ];

function processIssues(arr, arrayB) {
  return arr.reduce((result, item) => {
    const itemInB = arrayB.find(itemB => itemB.descendents_parent_issue_id == item.issue_id)

    if (itemInB) { 
      let child = [];
      child.push({ 
        issue_id: itemInB.descendents_issue_id,
        parent_issue_id: itemInB.descendents_parent_issue_id,
        issue: itemInB.descendents_issue,
        issue_code: itemInB.descendents_issue_code,
        entity_id: itemInB.descendents_entity_id,
        hierarchy_level: itemInB.descendents_hierarchy_level
      });
      item.children = child;  
    }

    if (item.children) {
      processIssues(item.children, arrayB)
    } 

    return [...result, item];
  }, []);
}

var sourceIssue = processIssues(issuesList, issues);
console.log(JSON.stringify(sourceIssue));
```

`Expected output`

```
[{
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "children": [{
        "issue_id": 7,
        "parent_issue_id": 2,
        "issue": "Breakdown",
        "issue_code": "bd7catA",
        "entity_id": null,
        "hierarchy_level": 2,
        "children": [{
            "issue_id": 881,
            "parent_issue_id": 7,
            "issue": "Hydraulic arm failure",
            "issue_code": null,
            "entity_id": 52,
            "hierarchy_level": 3
        },{
            "issue_id": 942,
            "parent_issue_id": 7,
            "issue": "Pump Overload",
            "issue_code": null,
            "entity_id": 52,
            "hierarchy_level": 3
          }]
    }]
}, {
    "issue_id": 1,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Loading",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
}, {
    "issue_id": 3,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Performance",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
}, {
    "issue_id": 4,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Quality",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
}]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```js
const issuesList = [
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 1,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Loading",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 3,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Performance",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 4,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Quality",
    "issue_code": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1
  }
];

const issues = [{
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
    "descendents_issue": "Breakdown",
    "descendents_issue_code": "bd7catA",
    "descendents_entity_id": null,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 2,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 881,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_issue": "Hydraulic arm failure",
    "descendents_issue_code": null,
    "descendents_entity_id": 52,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 3,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 881,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 8,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
    "descendents_issue": "Setup/ Changeover",
    "descendents_issue_code": "st8catA",
    "descendents_entity_id": null,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 2,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 8,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "parent_issue_id": null,
    "issue": "Availability",
    "issue_code": null,
    "entity_id": null,
    "hierarchy_level": 1,
    "descendents_issue_id": 942,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_issue": "Pump Overload",
    "descendents_issue_code": null,
    "descendents_entity_id": 52,
    "descendents_hierarchy_level": 3,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_issues_issue_id": 942,
    "descendents_issuesancestor_ancestor_issue_id": 2
  }
  ];

function processIssues(arr, arrayB) {
  return arr.reduce((result, item) => {
    const itemInB = arrayB.find(itemB => itemB.descendents_parent_issue_id == item.issue_id)

    if (itemInB) { 
      let child = [];
      child.push({ 
        issue_id: itemInB.descendents_issue_id,
        parent_issue_id: itemInB.descendents_parent_issue_id,
        issue: itemInB.descendents_issue,
        issue_code: itemInB.descendents_issue_code,
        entity_id: itemInB.descendents_entity_id,
        hierarchy_level: itemInB.descendents_hierarchy_level
      });
      item.children = processIssues(child, arrayB);  
    }

    return [...result, item];
  }, []);
}

var sourceIssue = processIssues(issuesList, issues);
console.log(JSON.stringify(sourceIssue));
```

Comment: getting the same output with the above code